# How to parse Etherscan?

Tags: python, parsing

How can I parse every single page for eth addresses from https://etherscan.io/token/generic-tokenholders2?a=0x6425c6be902d692ae2db752b3c268afadb099d3b&s=0&p=1 ? Then add it to .txt .

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, but you should take a look at the Etherscan API: https://etherscan.io/apis

Comment: Agree with @lungj. Also, I had a quick go with BeautifulSoup, and I think EtherScan probably won't let you scrape... _"<title>Access denied | etherscan.io used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>"_ Someone with the right skills might know how to get around this.

Comment: I'm trying to download all addresses to .txt . Etherscan API is not suitable there max 2k addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, possibly off-topic, but I had a play around with this. (Mainly because I thought I might need to use something similar to grab stuff in future that Etherscan's APIs don't return... )

The following Python2 code will grab what you're after. There's a hacky sleep in there to get around what I think is either something to do with how quickly the pages load, or some rate limiting imposed by Etherscan. I'm not sure.

Data gets written to a `.csv` file - a text file wouldn't be much fun.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time

RESULTS = "results.csv"
URL = "https://etherscan.io/token/generic-tokenholders2?a=0x6425c6be902d692ae2db752b3c268afadb099d3b&s=0&p="

def getData(sess, page):
    url = URL + page
    print("Retrieving page", page)
    return BeautifulSoup(sess.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

def getPage(sess, page):
    table = getData(sess, str(int(page))).find('table')
    return [[X.text.strip() for X in row.find_all('td')] for row in table.find_all('tr')]

def main():
    resp = requests.get(URL)
    sess = requests.Session()

    with open(RESULTS, 'wb') as f:
        wr = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        wr.writerow(map(str, "Rank Address Quantity Percentage".split()))
        page = 0
        while True:
            page += 1
            data = getPage(sess, page)

            # Even pages that don't contain the data we're
            # after still contain a table.
            if len(data) < 4:
                break
            else:
                for row in data:
                    wr.writerow(row)
                time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm sure it's not the best Python in the world.

Comment: This is it! Thank you!